# In Easytrieve output the count of different values in a column

Tags: mainframe, easytrieve

```
input                  this column   
1       a     b        5000
1       a     b        5000
1       a     b        5001
1       a     b        5000


output                 sort count no of times 5000 & 5001 was there
5000                     3
5001                     1
```

We need the no of times a single number has occurred in that column. I have done that in JCL, but need that to be done in Easytrieve.

In JCL we simply do :

```
                    TRAILER3=(25,4,                    
       ';',                     
        COUNT=(M10,             
               LENGTH=10)))
```

How is this done in Easytrieve?

Answer (score 0):

Your example with a SORT control card (it is not JCL) will not give you the output you expect for the sample you show. That SORT control card would work only if the file is in sequence by that value, which you do not show in your sample.

If we assume that your file will be in sequence, and you want the Easytrieve Report to give similar output to your SORT control card, then

Look at SEQUENCE, specifying the field, CONTROL, specifying the field (FINAL NOPRINT if you don't want a final total). It looks like you want a SUMMARY report, so look at that. You can use a field with a value of one appearing on a REPORT LINE but without the detail lines (which is what SUMMARY gives you).

If you can't get there with this, update your question to explain what is not working when you attempt it.

It would have got you more viewings if you'd also tagged the question `mainframe`.